# Why do I get a syntax error in Python despite using exitStack() as in the doc?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute some python's code and can't figure out what's the issue :

```
def elboguide(design, dim=10):
    # pyro.set_rng_seed(10)
    theta_mu = pyro.param("theta_mu", torch.zeros(dim, 1, 2, 2))
    theta_sig = pyro.param("theta_sig", torch.ones(dim, 1, 2, 2),
                           constraint=torch.distributions.constraints.positive)
    batch_shape = design.shape[:-2]
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        for plate in iter_plates_to_shape(batch_shape):
            stack.enter_context(plate)
        theta_shape = batch_shape + theta_mu.shape[-2:]
        pyro.sample("theta", dist.Normal(
            theta_mu.expand(theta_shape),
            theta_sig.expand(theta_shape)).to_event(2)
        )
```

The issue is in this function, more specifically on the line

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
```

When running the code I only get the error :

> File "C:\Users\natha\Documents\prog\python_dev\RL-BOED\RL-BOED\source.py", line 52
> with ExitStack() as stack:
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

the documentation of contextlib shows an use case where the syntax is exactly the same :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

What is wrong with this code ? I'm using Python 3.11.0 by the way.

Comment: For one, the indentation is wrong, and also there are a bunch of missing imports and variable definitions. Please make sure the code provided in the question can be copied-and-pasted _without changes_ to get the _exact_ same error you have.

Comment: Ok I'll complete the code

Comment: @CharlesDuffy To be honest, I was hoping that someone could help me without procuring the whole code, as it has many dependencies and can't be easily run on his own. :/

Comment: We don't ever want your _whole_ code; we want a [mre] -- something written specifically to be the shortest, simplest possible code that produces the same problem when run without changes.